# MSMQ prevent publishing of duplicate messages (as in Azure Service Bus)

Tags: c#, msmq, azureservicebus

I have a watcher process that detect some changes (for example in a filesystem) and pushes new messages into a queue. I have a unique way to identify each message.

I want to prevent publishing the same message twice and I don't want to keep any explicit state on this watcher.

I've read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx) that Azure Service Bus Queues support Duplicate Detection on the sender side, that is exactly what I'm looking for, but for MSMQ.

Is there a similar feature on MSMQ? If not, how can I support a similar feature on top of MSMQ.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried approach described in
 [Microsoft Message Queuing duplicate message removal mechanism](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255546), there are more info in John Breakwell's [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/04/02/how-msmq-prevents-duplicate-messages.aspx)

hope it would help you

Comment: Looks like the link is broken